# Modernizr build combination with child theme support

Tags: wordpress, themes, modernizr

I'm building a WordPress theme which I intend to make available for download, and I want developers to be able to make child themes for it. I would like to use Modernizr in it, but not an entire Modernizr build with every bell and whistle. Just a bare-bones build for the features I need, but also with support for child theme builders who want to add more Modernizr features. Is there a way to do that? I know Modernizr has an addTest() function, but I don't know if this would cover all bases if I add it in to my Modernizr build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modernizr is going to add support for multiple versions being hosted at the same time in the future, but in the mean time the best thing you could do is include the bare bones build, and a comment saying that a build with the follow features is required if they want to modify it.